# ChatScript Integration with Python application

Tags: nlp, chatbot, chatscript

How to integrate ChatScript [scripting language] with my python interface?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: @kuzyn No, Unfortunately

Comment: If you're still looking into solving this, have a look into this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233340/sending-string-via-socket-python and review this ChatScript document: https://goo.gl/H8zH8K then try out your code and post it in your question if you can't manage to make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

what do you means with "my Python interface" ?

About how to wrap CS inside a Python app, you maybe want to realize a client / server interface (realizing a client in Python):

https://github.com/bwilcox-1234/ChatScript/blob/master/WIKI/CLIENTS-AND-SERVERS/ChatScript-ClientServer-Manual.md

BTW, I realized a client Ruby gem (maybe helpfull):

http://www.github.com/solyaris/rChatscript

Otherwise if you want to call Python methods from CS scripts, you can use ^TCPopen(...), having realized an HTTP Server Python-side...