# How I can to create python(or swift) TCP client for my TCP c# server?

Tags: c#, python, swift, tcp

How I can to create python(or swift) TCP client for my TCP c# server?

c# API for my TCP server:

```
Client client = Client();
bool Connect()
{
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo("login", "pass");
    NetworkConnectionParam connectionParams = new NetworkConnectionParam("127.0.0.1", 4021);
    try
    {
        client.Connect(connectionParams,userInfo,ClientInitFlags.Empty);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return client.IsStarted;
}
```

I try it(python) :

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 4021))
```

But I don't uderstand how I must to send my login and password (like in API for c#).

Comment: Why did you delete  your previous question and post an exact duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I don`t undestand what you want to implement.
If you want to run Python code in C#, then look at this [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/)

If you want to implement TCP client in C#, then try smth like this:

```
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Sockets;

 class Program
{
    static int port = 8005; // your port
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get address to run socket
        var ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);

        // create socket
        var listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            // binding
            listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);

            // start listen
            listenSocket.Listen(10);

            Console.WriteLine("Server is working");

            while (true)
            {
                Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
                // recieve message
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0; // quantity of received bytes 
                byte[] data = new byte[256]; // data buffer

                do
                {
                    bytes = handler.Receive(data);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (handler.Available>0);

                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + builder.ToString());

                // send response
                string message = "your message recieved";
                data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                handler.Send(data);
                // close socket
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to create a python TCP client (on python, not c# and not python code in c#) for TCP server (on c#). python client for c# server. I have c# API for my TCP server: ```Client client = Client();
bool Connect()
{
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo("login", "pass");
    NetworkConnectionParam connectionParams = new NetworkConnectionParam("127.0.0.1", 4021);
    try
    {
        client.Connect(connectionParams,userInfo,ClientInitFlags.Empty);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return client.IsStarted;
}```

Comment: I try ```sock.connect(('localhost', 4021))``` in python. But I don't uderstand how I must to send my login and password (like in API for c#).

Comment: @Xcodebeginner first of all which "type" of auth you want to implement? If you want just simple send login and password then here is how to send data in Python:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233340/sending-string-via-socket-python
and also you need to modify your code in c# in order to receive this data.

Comment: Thanks). I have a server(c#) and I can't to change some part of code on this server. But I hawe API (c#) for this server. And I must to use this API. ```c#``` ```Client client = Client(); bool Connect() { UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo("login", "pass"); NetworkConnectionParam connectionParams = new NetworkConnectionParam("127.0.0.1", 4021); try { client.Connect(connectionParams,userInfo,ClientInitFlags.Empty); } catch { return false; } return client.IsStarted; }``` I dont know how i must to create something like that on another programming language(python, swift).